# ReactRouter - Unable to pass props OR params to "Link to" for Component

Tags: reactjs, react-router-v4, react-props, react-component

I am new to React and trying to do something very simple. I am accessing an API in my parent component. I want to access the ID of each object and then pass it to the child component. I have managed to get the ID to show in the URI, so /offers/:id . I have tried two things:

1. Passing the ID in "Link to" to then access from my component with either "props.location.state" or "this.props.location.state" - didn't work.
2. Accessing ID from URI via params "props.match.params" - didn't work.

Could anyone please tell me what I am doing wrong?

App.js :

```
export default class App extends Component {

    render() {

        return (
            <div>
                <Switch>
                    <Route exact path='/offers' component={ OffersContainer }/>
                    <Route path='/offers/:id' component={ OfferContainer} />
                </Switch>
            </div>
        );
     }
  }
```

Parent Component where API is accessed:

```
 <Link to={{
     pathname: `/offers/${offer.id}`,
         state: {
             id: offer.id
         }
 }}> Object path </Link>
```

Child Component where I need the ID:

```
componentDidMount() {
    const { id } = props.location.state
}
```

It always comes back to the same error "props is not defined"

Answer (score 0):

In Child Component, since it is a class-component, you have to use `this.props`:

```
componentDidMount() {
    const { id } = this.props.match.params
    console.log(id)

    fetch(`/api/offers/${id}`)
      ....
}
```